# Using RegEx to match every segment of a line that starts with a specified term and stopping when that term occurs again.

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

As the title suggests I am trying to figure out how to use RegEx when reading a line from a text file and store every occurrence of a match in a list. I know using the findall method would do this but I first need to create an appropriate RegEx. What I have so far will only select the first instance of the expression and only if there are multiple occurrences per line. Any advice on how to get it to give a unique match for every keyword and all the follows it (stopping when it finds the keyword again)? Here is what I have so far.

```
(.?(NUL|ETX|SOH|ENQ|CAN|SUB|ESC)+<\d\d\d>.*?)(?=(.?(NUL|ETX|SOH|ENQ|CAN|SUB|ESC)))
```

And the content I am testing it this:

3NUL<123>lkjasdf lfdl;kja  (432) adsfa sd 4ETX<342> sdfasdf asfds  asdfa4(1 234)

4ETX<345> asdfasdf

NULSOH<342> sadfasd fasasdf asd 4ETX<345> asdfasdf

Comment: In your examples, which segments of each line do you want?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `(?s)(NUL|ETX|SOH|ENQ|CAN|SUB|ESC).*?(?=(\1))`

Comment: Yea, some examples would be great. @revo's example is what I instantly thought, but there are going to be some issues potentially. You'll match from the first `NUL` to the 3rd line and then, because of how regex matches left to right, [you'll miss the `ETX` on the very first line](https://regex101.com/r/kK2vC7/1) and not end up matching anything else.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want? [https://regex101.com/r/mA9gC8/1](https://regex101.com/r/mA9gC8/1)

Comment: Yeah, seems like you need [`(?s)(CAN|NUL|E(?:TX|NQ|SC)|S(?:OH|UB))(?:(?!\1).)*`](https://regex101.com/r/nG3iF1/1). Here is a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/CqGVs3). Or if you need overlapping matches, [`(?s)(?=((CAN|NUL|E(?:TX|NQ|SC)|S(?:OH|UB))(?:(?!\2).)*))`](https://regex101.com/r/nG3iF1/2).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need

```
(?s)(CAN|NUL|E(?:TX|NQ|SC)|S(?:OH|UB))(?:(?!\1).)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG3iF1/1).

The `(CAN|NUL|E(?:TX|NQ|SC)|S(?:OH|UB))` is a Group 1 capturing your terms (the pattern is a bit optimized to avoid unnecessary backtracking) and `(?:(?!\1).)*` is a tempered greedy token that matches any text but the beginning of the term matched (thus, matching up to the next same term).

Or if you need overlapping matches, use

```
(?s)(?=((CAN|NUL|E(?:TX|NQ|SC)|S(?:OH|UB))(?:(?!\2).)*))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG3iF1/2). This patter contains a capture group inside a positive unanchored lookahead to get all overlapping matches.

Here is a [Python demo](http://ideone.com/CqGVs3):

```
import re

s = "3NUL<123>lkjasdf lfdl;kja  (432) adsfa sd 4ETX<342> sdfasdf asfds  asdfa4(1 234)  \n\n4ETX<345> asdfasdf\n\nNULSOH<342> sadfasd fasasdf asd 4ETX<345> asdfasdf "

#non-overlapping
p = re.compile(r'(CAN|NUL|E(?:TX|NQ|SC)|S(?:OH|UB))(?:(?!\1).)*', re.DOTALL)
print([x.group(0) for x in p.finditer(s)])
# => ['NUL<123>lkjasdf lfdl;kja  (432) adsfa sd 4ETX<342> sdfasdf asfds  asdfa4(1 234)  \n\n4ETX<345> asdfasdf\n\n', 'NULSOH<342> sadfasd fasasdf asd 4ETX<345> asdfasdf ']

#overlapping
p = re.compile(r'(?=((CAN|NUL|E(?:TX|NQ|SC)|S(?:OH|UB))(?:(?!\2).)*))', re.DOTALL)
print([x.group(1) for x in p.finditer(s)])
# => ['NUL<123>lkjasdf lfdl;kja  (432) adsfa sd 4ETX<342> sdfasdf asfds  asdfa4(1 234)  \n\n4ETX<345> asdfasdf\n\n', 'ETX<342> sdfasdf asfds  asdfa4(1 234)  \n\n4', 'ETX<345> asdfasdf\n\nNULSOH<342> sadfasd fasasdf asd 4', 'NULSOH<342> sadfasd fasasdf asd 4ETX<345> asdfasdf ', 'SOH<342> sadfasd fasasdf asd 4ETX<345> asdfasdf ', 'ETX<345> asdfasdf ']
```